# When I vote one of the choices it shows error (can only concatenate str (not "int") to str)

Tags: python, django, web-applications

[image]

I am following Django official documentation tutorial to make a poll app. I am currently stuck on part 4. So when I select one of the choices it shows an error:

> can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I can't understand. I am I trying to add a string to integer, where is the problem in the code?

Here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Can you tell where the exception is raised?

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: i am sorry guys i am actuall new to programming i posted a screenshot of error

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you showed a better error description; this way, it would be easier to help you.

Anyway, I suppose the problem is here: `selected_choice.votes += 1`. Probably (I am just assuming from what I see), `selected_choice.votes` is of type `str`; therefore, when you try to add the `int` value `1`, Python tells you that it `can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`.

To understand that message a little bit, in Python, string sums are string concatenations: `'hi' + ' I'm Rodrigo' == 'hi I'm Rodrigo'`. That is the reason why it understands that you are trying to *concatenate* an string value with an integer value.

Make sure the variable where you are storing the number of votes is an integer, or try casting it to `int` and then back to `str` (I wouldn't really recommend this).

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am sorry i am a newbie to programming i added a screenshot of error also the vaue of votes i have set is::  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, I believe the problem is what I mentioned in the answer; selected_choice.votes is a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You trying to concatenate integer to the string. As the traceback says, the error is in the line 34, the line 34 is:

`selected_choice.votes += 1`

You can comment this line and try to check first which value exactly contains in the variable:

```
print(selected_choice.votes)
print(type(selected_choice.votes))
```

(Then check the output in the command line)